# fread and fwrite in C

Tags: c, file, binary, fwrite, fread

I'm trying to make a program that creates and reads a binary file, which contains "struct elements"; can you please tell me what I did wrong?
I got errors telling me that "s" is not a pointer in function fread()... so I declared ELEM *s; instead of ELEM s;

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct element{
    char name[80];
    int p;
}ELEM;

void create()
{
    FILE *f;
    int d=0;
    char c;
    ELEM *s;
    f=fopen("file.bin","wb");
    do{
    printf("Add elements to file?: (y/n)");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if (c=='y')
    {
        printf("Name=");
        gets((*s).name);
        printf("P=");
        scanf("%d",(*s).p);
        fwrite(s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
    }
    } while(d==0);
    fclose(f);
}

void show()
{
    FILE *f;
    ELEM *s;
    f=fopen("file.bin","rb");
    while(feof(f)!=NULL)
    {
        fread(s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
        puts((*s).name);
        printf("\t%d\n",(*s).p);
    }
    fclose(f);
}

void add()
{
    FILE *f;
    int d=0;
    char c;
    ELEM *s;
    f=fopen("file.bin","ab");
    do{
    printf("Add elements to file?: (y/n)");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%c",&c);
    if (c=='y')
    {
        printf("Name=");
        gets((*s).name);
        printf("P=");
        scanf("%d",(*s).p);
        fwrite(s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
    }
    } while(d==0);
    fclose(f);
}


/*void function()
{

}*/

int main()
{
    int k=0,r;
    do{
        printf("1 - create file\n2 - add elements to fil\n3 - show elements\n4 - put unique elements in another file\n5 - exit program\n");
        scanf("%d",&r);
        switch(r)
        {
            case 1 : create(); break;
            case 2 : add(); break;
            case 3 : show(); break;
            case 4 : printf("Function not defined!\n"); break;
            case 5 : k=1; break;
            default : printf("Command unrecognized!\n");
        }
    } while(k==0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: On a side note: `fflush(stdin)` is definitely wrong. Also, `gets()` cannot be used safely. See `fgets()` instead (you can pass it `stdin`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first parameter passed to **[fwrite](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/fread.html)** should be an address, and the variable whose address you pass must have enough memory to hold the number of objects you plan to read.

So there are two ways:

**Creating Variable on Stack:**

You allocate the variable on stack and pass its address to `fwrite`

```
ELEM s;
fwrite(&s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
```

or

**Dynamic Memory allocation:**

```
ELEM *s;
```

Should be allocated an memory equivalent to hold no of objects of type `ELEM` that you want to read.

```
ELEM *s = malloc(sizeof *s);
```

In this case remember to free the memory once done with your use:

```
free(s);
```

Answer (score 3):

You declared a pointer but assigned no memory to it. You should revert to a normal variable:

```
ELEM s;

/* ... */

fwrite(&s,sizeof(ELEM),1,f);
       ^
```

Alternatively, in your current code you should do this:

```
ELEM *s = calloc(1, sizeof *s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating the pointer `s` in your `create`  function. You probably want something like

```
 s = malloc(sizeof(*s));
 memset (s, 0, sizeof(*s));
```

etc.

And you really should learn to compiler with `gcc -Wall -g` and to use the `gdb` debugger.

Also, take time to read a good book about programming in C.

Comment: Don't forget to call `free(s);` at the appropriate place. Use `valgrind` to ensure your program don't leak too much...

Answer (score 0):

Well, your problems is in the scanf. scanf should get a pointer, so change `(*s).p` to `&(*s).p` (or even `&s->p`)

Answer (score 0):

You should have allocated the pointer to struct ELEM
Assuming this is C:

```
 ELEM *s = malloc(sizeof(ELEM));
```

If it is C++ just add a cast in front

```
 ELEM *s = (ELEM*) malloc(sizeof(ELEM));
```